# Smart banner for safari doesn't show my app information on iOS, how to make it work?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, smartbanner

I'm using the following meta tag to show a smart banner on the iOS safari browser to open and install the app, copied from [apple guide to smartbanners](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners):

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=6444793650">
```

this works for every app, except ours!
the app id is:6444793650

I guess since the app is fresh, apple's lazy crawlers couldn't find time to crawl it!

Comment: did you close the `<meta>` tag?